# cannot connect to destination host with AWS Polly

Tags: amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I am testing AWS Polly. I got an error saying 'cannot connect to destination host'.
This happened right here.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip($"{Application.persistentDataPath}/audio.mp3", AudioType.MPEG);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);  <============
    }
    else
    {
        ......
    }
```

I signed up AWS and got some access keys as root user for Polly.
Do I need to do something more to access AWS services?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I solved it. Prefixing file:// with the file path will fix the problem.